# Retry if failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! 1 PHP

Tags: php

Im trying to open an api and extract some data and about 1/5 times the script runs it errors with a

> PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://192.168.1.52/home.cgi): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! 1

I would like to retry opening the api on error and then follow through with the rest of the code

This is running on a Pi using PHP5

```
$inverterDataURL = "http://".$dataManagerIP."/home.cgi";


$context = stream_context_create(array('http'=>array('protocol_version'=>'1.1')));
$result = file_get_contents('http://192.168.1.11/home.cgi', false, $context);
```

20% of the time when running the script it errors trying to open the api and without the api being open i can't grab any data out of it.
the rest of the script runs through fine when it opens correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a loop for the retry logic that breaks when the result succeeds. A `do ... while` loop is used here because it guarantees that it'll be run at least once (therefore  guaranteeing that `$result` will be set to *something*). When the `file_get_contents` fails, `$result` will be false:

```
<?php

$context = stream_context_create(array('http'=>array('protocol_version'=>'1.1')));

do {
  $result = file_get_contents('http://127.0.0.1/home.cgi', false, $context);
  if (!$result) {
    echo "Waiting 3 seconds.\n";
    sleep(3);
  }
} while( !$result);
```

If the server goes down, you'll probably want something to break the loop after a few tries. This bit will stop trying after 5 failures.

```
<?php

$context = stream_context_create(array('http'=>array('protocol_version'=>'1.1')));

$attempts = 0;
do {
  $attempts++;
  echo "Attempt $attempts\n";
  $result = file_get_contents('http://127.0.0.1/home.cgi', false, $context);
  if (!$result) {
    echo "Attempt $attempts has failed. Waiting 3 seconds.\n";
    sleep(3);
  }
} while( !$result && $attempts < 5);
```

Comment: Thanks i can't do anything until the solar inverter wakes up so will see how it goes  tomorrow but putting it into my code it retries 5 times as it should when the inverter is switched off.

Comment: Worked a treat Save me copious amounts of time googling and finding nothing that can just retry the 1 line like you have done. and all looked too overly complicated. not that yours doesn't look like that to me but i knew what to do with it straight away